# Algorithm to find all the possible cuts in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Is there any efficient algorithm which can help me to list out all the cuts in an undirected weighted graph. I want to find out what are all the possible cut sets with source or one of the nodes on one side and sink or another node on the other.

Please note that the priority is to find all the cut sets and not the minimum cut.

For example, consider a graph with the following edge lists: s-->a-->t s-->b-->t

The cut sets of the above graph is : {sa,sb}, {at,bt}, {sb,at}, {sa,bt},{sa,sb,at}, {sa,sb,bt},{sa,bt,at}, {sb,at,bt},{sa,sb,at,bt}

Answer (score 2):

Just enumerate all subsets of vertices other than the source and sink...

Comment: i can't understand this will not give the result above.can you explain please.

Comment: Given a subset $A$ of the vertices other than the source $s$ and sink $t$, the corresponding cut-set is the set of all edges with one vertex in $A \cup \{s\}$ and the other in 
its complement.

Comment: yeah that's convincing...thank you very much.